# Gaussian elimination for rings with zero divisors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, inverse, gaussian-elimination

Does Gaussian elimination work on unitary commutative rings with zero divisors?

If so, what is the correct way to use it? Clearly, it is not possible to rely on division because zero divisors are not invertible. (And since we are talking about a general ring, not all elements are invertible anyways.) But is it OK to multiply a row by a zero divisor?

Comment: Let $ab=0$ be zero divisors. First multiply with $a$ and then multiply with $b$. Do you think this preserves the solutions?

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand why it doesn't work.